# hive llap - which execution engine supported? spark,mr, tez

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, mapreduce, tez

The documentation is not clear. All blog post examples about Hive LLAP (Long Live and Process) uses the Tez execution engine, but can Spark/MR hive engines also use LLAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive2 has deprecated MR execution, but all are still  possible

Tez is the first class execution engine because [Hive on Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started) is still under active development

Comment: Haven't tried it. You tell me. The property still exists. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-QueryandDDLExecution  Note: Tez requires less resources than Spark and when benchmarked running queries on ORC+ZLIB format vs SparkSQL on Parquet+Snappy, Tez is faster